# How do I use GREP to find and replace all hyphens between numbers in an InDesign document?

Tags: grep, adobe, adobe-indesign

I am working on a multi-language book, and I need to find and replace all hyphens with en-dashes that occur between numbers in the citations section. I need to avoid all hyphens that exist between roman letters.

If I use a GREP [0-9]-[0-9] it selects the numbers before and after the hyphen and I have to manually select the hyphen and replace it with an en-dash. This is labor intensive.

Is there a way for me to find the hyphen that exists between the numbers, but EXCLUDE the numbers themselves from being highlighted? This way I can run a the Find and Replace to change what will probably be 1000+ manual changes?

I tried using GREP [0-9]-[0-9] to find the hyphens, but then couldn't find a way to have the find and replace keep the existing numbers.

Comment: With `grep` you can not replace anything. I suggest to use `sed` or `awk`.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what lookaheads and lookbehinds are for`

```
(?<=[0-9])-(?=[0-9])
```

Comment: I wish I saw this a bit earlier. That's exactly what I needed!!

Answer (score 0):

If you have selected GREP, another way could be to use 2 capture groups and use those 2 groups in the replacement with an en-dash in between.

```
([0-9])-([0-9])
```

Replace with `$1–$2`

Comment: This is great, too. Thank you both for your responses!